# VBA to programmatically put value in cell when adding data validation list

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I am fully versed in VBA but not certain if this is possible or not as I couldn't find anything while searching for the past 15 minutes.

I add a data validation list in the usual manner

```
startCell.Offset(1, 2).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Categories"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True        
End With
```

But when the routine finishes none of the values are selected and therefore the cell is blank.

Is there a way to set the cell value when adding the data validation, i.e. a default value maybe the first item in the data validation list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
With startCell.Offset(1, 2)
    With .Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:= xlBetween, Formula1:="=Categories"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With
    .Value = Range("Categories").Cells(1).Value
End With
```

Comment: Brilliant, how did I not think of that. I was too focused on it being part of the creation of the data validation. Thank you. Ill accept when the time allows.